# How can I rearrange the order of OSes in the boot menu?

Tags: windows-7, grub2

I installed Ubuntu 10.10 with Windows 7 Ultimate in dual boot configuration. Everything seems to be working fine. I have a small doubt, is it possible to Re-arrange the Boot menu that appears when you start your machine?
Currently Ubuntu is at top and Windows is the very last one. If we dont make a choice for some seconds, it automatically boots Ubuntu. Can I swap this with Windows being default if the user doesn't make any choice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this on the [forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1309890), it is a little old, but the process should be the same. I just tried it and it does work as it should.

First install startup-manager via Ubuntu Software Center, you can find the package by searching for startup. [image]

Then, open the startup manager and select Windows 7 as the default, close, restart and it should work.
 [image]

Comment: your first screenshot shows a different package selected - can you update it to highlight startup-manager?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. Just edit `/etc/default/grub` file and change the value of `GRUB_DEFAULT` to the value you want. 0 is for first os in the GRUB menu (I hope windows 7 in 4th position in your GRUB, if then the value of  GRUB_DEFAULT should be 3).
and then run `sudoupdate-grub` command.

in detail:

open a terminal

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

change the value of `GRUB_DEFAULT`

save and exit vi editor (press <kbd>esc</kbd> and then type `:wq`)
then run the command

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: @t3ch - you can say thanks on this site by clicking the upwards pointing chevron next to the answer :D . Also, click the tick next to the answer you think is the best. See the [faq](http://askubuntu.com/faq).

Comment: @dv3500ea :D will do

Comment: So what happens when Ubuntu releases an updated kernel and Windows shifts from position 4 to position 6?  Is there a way to specify "the last one"?

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can

```
sudo mv /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober /etc/grub.d/09_os-prober && sudo update-grub
```

Comment: AFAIK this is the only method that will work even upon installing a second kernel

Answer (score 1):

## [StartUp-Manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/p/startup-manager) [image: install StartUp-Manager]

StartUp-Manager can be used to select the default operating system for grub. Once installed, go to
**System > Administration > Startup-Manager**
then choose Windows from the drop down menu.

[image]